# Update table from model when changeing value MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, html-table

I have my table looking like this:

```
@{var i = true;}
@{var rowID = 1;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (i)
    {
        <tr id="@rowID">
            <td align="center">
                @rowID
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center" id="startValue">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartValue)
            </td>
        </tr>
        i = false;
        rowID++;
    }
    <tr id="@rowID">
        <td align="center">
            @rowID
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div contenteditable>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    rowID++;
}
```

I have made each cell in the table editable using them inside div-tags. The models are depending on eachother, that means that the object on the second row is depending on the attribute values on the object in the first row, and so on. I wan't the table to update from where I change (if I change row 5, I want the row below to change depending on what I change  on row 5). I have no idea how to make the table update like this and would really appriciate some help with this.

The method in CalclationController that create's the model objects:

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail(FormCollection form)
    {

        List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
        Calculation calc = new Calculation();
        calc.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(form["startdate"]);
        calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
        calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
        calc.InterestAmount = (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
        calc.Amortization = (2000 - (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30));
        calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) - calc.Amortization;
        calc.StartValue = Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]);
        cList.Add(calc);
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(form["PaymentPeriods"]); i++)
        {
            Calculation calcBefore = cList.Last();
            calc = new Calculation();
            calc.Date = calcBefore.Date.AddMonths(1);
            calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
            calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
            calc.InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * calc.InterestRate / 360 * 30);
            calc.Amortization = (calc.InvoiceAmount - (calcBefore.PresentValue * calc.InterestRate / 360 * 30));
            calc.PresentValue = calcBefore.PresentValue - calc.Amortization;
            cList.Add(calc);
        }
        return PartialView("ShowDetail", cList);
    }
```

So, is there any way to update my table from the row selected and the ones below?

Answer (score 0):

you mean changing row data automatically depends on the row you just edit data of it?
i think you can use javascript to flash the row below when you finish editing, and use ajax to update the new datas

Comment: Yes thats what I mean...you have any small example of this?